# NSCalendar NSDateComponents weekofYear return 1 with date 2014-12-31

Tags: objective-c, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I want to get weekofYear with date '2014-12-31' ,but it always return 1 not 52 
here is my code:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSlog(@"%i",dateComponent.weekOfYear);


output  "1";
```

I know result is right, but I want get "52" not '1',how to fix it?

Comment: Presumably the first week of 2015 is the week containing Jan 1, 2015.  (Though admittedly this behavior is not well documented.)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use the `yearForWeekOfYear` property of the `NSDateComponents` instance. If the `yearForWeekOfYear` is after the year of the date passed to `components:fromDate:`, then it is week 52.

E.g.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit | NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSInteger weekOfYear = dateComponent.weekOfYear;
if (dateComponent.yearForWeekOfYear > dateComponent.year)
    weekOfYear = 52;
NSLog(@"%i",weekOfYear); // 52
```

Comment: Or sometimes week 53. See here: http://kalenderwoche.net/alle-kalenderwochen-2009.php (sorry for german, but numbers are the same ;)

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`minimumDaysInFirstWeek`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/setMinimumDaysInFirstWeek:) property of the `NSCalendar` instance before obtaining the date components.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
calendar.minimumDaysInFirstWeek = 7; // the week has to be completely within one year

NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"%i",dateComponent.weekOfYear); // 52
```

Comment: But this will also make 2015-1-1 week 52.

Answer (score 0):

IF the week is 1 (first days of 2015 or last few days of 2014)

AND the day is greater than 20 (so it's one of the last three days of 2014)

THEN (calculate the week of your date minus 5 days, and add 1).

This will make the last few days of the year into their own week, which is sometimes week 52, sometimes week 53. And it works with European and US calendars.

You'll need to think what you want to do if Jan 1st is in the last week of the previous year. Might make it week 0. So really going with the standard and accepting what iOS tells you is the saner way to do it.