# pandas datetime returns 1 for weekofyear of 2018-12-31

Tags: pandas, datetime, time

I'm trying to get the year and weekofyear for partitionioning, e.g '2018-52' or '2019-01'
When using the pandas datatime functions I get '2018-01' for '2018-12-31 19:35:59'.

This seems to be related to [NSCalendar NSDateComponents weekofYear return 1 with date 2014-12-31](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715711/nscalendar-nsdatecomponents-weekofyear-return-1-with-date-2014-12-31)

But I still hope this can be solved with pandas datetime without hacking something like special handling of `weekofyear == 1`.

```
import pandas as pd
date = pd.to_datetime('2018-12-31 19:35:59')
print('%d-%d' % (date.year, date.weekofyear))
>> 2018-01
```

I would be fine with both 2018-52 and 2019-01.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is default as Monday as first date of the year and week number from 00-53,and you should using symbol `'U'`

```
pd.Series(date).dt.strftime('%Y-%U')
Out[170]: 
0    2018-52
dtype: object
```

And this will turn first day of the 2019 become 2019-00

```
pd.Series(pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01 19:35:59')).dt.strftime('%Y-%U')
Out[171]: 
0    2019-00
dtype: object
```